# Unix - C - Using exec to execute same program

Tags: c, exec

In my C program I want to recursively call my program's source code, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    execlp("a.out", "a.out", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming a.out is the result of the compilation of the above source code, by using

```
gcc program.c
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Hello World
```

As if I haven't wrote the execlp line. ¿Is it anything wrong with it? The output I want to achieve is the following:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
...
```

Obviously, in my program it'd be a stop condition, but for simplicity I'm not considering it right now.

So, how could it be done?
Thank you.

Comment: You don't run the program using `a.out`. You run it using `./a.out`, right?

Answer (score 0):

To correct your code, change `execlp` command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    execlp("./a.out", "", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Then run it using `./a.out` into your terminal.

BTW you could have the same output using loops: `for`, `while`.

Answer (score 0):

To generate that kind of output, you should use looping instead of recursion. As you mentioned, you will want to add a stop condition...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    while (true)  // To do: add a stop condition.
    {
        printf("Hello World\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```